# Implementing setupHover() for UIButton without user interaction?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, uikit

I have a UIButton that I have disabled user interaction, but when I disable the user interaction, the UIPointerEffect.highlight doesn't work anymore (snaps cursor to button when using trackpad on iPad). It does work properly when the user interaction is enabled but unfortunately that's not an option. Is there anything I can do to enable the .highlight effect without having the user interaction enabled?

Comment: I'm not sure, but probably not. Think it through from a user perspective. Why should it work when user interaction is disabled. Since the actual button simply doesn't work - why make it appear to the user like it would? More, it **you**, as the app owner, that has control over enabling/disabling "user interaction". You likely - hopefully? - have a very good reason to (a) show a "flat" UIButton but (b) disabling it.

Comment: (Note, I do this too for an app that needs an image to edit *before* the edit button is "enabled". But Since my app flow has an image in each window *after* opening one through either an image picker or drag/drop, I simply hide the edit button in a navigation bar until there is one. Could you set the `isHidden` property for the button instead of confusing the user by showing something that is disabled instead? Please note that I put "flat" in quotes - new users may (but usually not) know what is a button as opposed to a label since iOS7.